# What is role of transistor in STACKFET configuration?

Tags: transistors, switch-mode-power-supply

I found such circuit configuration in stackfet in 10W power supply. What is role of transistor Q1, Capacitor C4 and resistor R11 ? What is meaning of Base-Emitter shorted transistor ?

[image]

Comment: It looks like Q1 is working here as overvoltage protection for IC.  From what I remember Vces breakdown voltage will be less than Vceo = 160V. R11 will limit the breakdown current.  And C4 together with 1M resistors form a bias network for Q2 (C4 as bypass capacitor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C4 is a decoupling capacitor. Q1 is an avalanche clamp when collector is much higher than emitter. Q1 also acts as a reverse voltage clamp when base is above collector. Q1 is basically a fast Zener-like diode that limits the voltage on C4. The voltage on C4 biases Q2's gate.

Q2 can act as a source follower and limit the voltage on the chip below.